# How to create graphs in Excel 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have data in CSV format, and I want to create a few graphs.  I was looking around in google for how to do that, but it seems like most help about Excel graphs does not match my version of Excel (2007).

The CSV is split into columns. Some columns are symbols, some columns are numbers.
I want to:

1. Take a column of a symbol and two columns of number, and create a scatter plot where in the x-y we have the numbers and the color of the dot is according to the symbol (a color allocated per symbol).
2. I want to be able to filter from the scatter plot all data where a certain, another column, does not equal a certain number (i.e. if the data is columns A,B,C,D and the symbol is in A and the xy plot includes B,C, I want to filter out all data points such that D is not 0.05).
3. I want to create an xy plot (a line) with two columns, where all points from the same symbol are aggregated to create a single line. Each symbol will have its own line.

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/demo-create-charts-in-excel-2007-HA010200499.aspx

Comment: Your problem is that you're working in a CSV. Save the file as an Excel file and you're good to go.

Comment: You've said you want to use 2 columns of numbers. Are the different columns important? Do you want to be able to tell in the plot which column the data came from?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a [PivotChart](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/CH010064848.aspx). You may wish to start with [creating a PivotTable](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-or-delete-a-pivottable-or-pivotchart-report-HP010089893.aspx). And as has been mentioned in your comments, you'll probably want to save it as a xlsx to get all of the charting goodness.

Answer (score 0):

I tried making a pivot chart example for you, but didn't manage to achieve what you wanted easily. If you've succeeded with that line of testing then great.

Otherwise, I've made an example for you here that shows sorting and plotting the data manually:
[example spreadsheet](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/82232901/RandomShare/Superuser/2016-21-08%20graph%20help.xls)

Step through each tab to see how to format the data, filter and plot.